# iDRAC7 - discover Host Name, OS Name, OS Version when running RHEL 6?

Tags: rhel6, drac

Just picked up a Dell PowerEdge R720 which comes with an iDRAC 7, and am wondering how to get the host operating system (Red Hat 6) to automatically report the hostname, os name, and os version to the DRAC without having to manually set these parameters.

Is there something I need to install / configure on the OS side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the answer is to install the following packages and enable their services. This has been wrapped into a single shell script for convenience:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
wget -q -O - http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/bootstrap.cgi | bash
yum install OpenIPMI srvadmin-base srvadmin-storageservices srvadmin-racsvc srvadmin-idrac7 srvadmin-omcommon -y
chkconfig ipmi on
service ipmi start
/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/srvadmin-services.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1760.openmanage-server-administrator-omsa.aspx

Linux Install

1. Log on as root to the system running the supported Red Hat Enterprise Linux or SUSE Linux Enterprise Server operating system where you want to install the managed system components.
2. Insert the Dell Systems Management Tools and Documentation DVD into the DVD drive.
3. If necessary, use the command line to mount the DVD using a command such as:
   **mount /dev/dvdrom /mnt/dvdrom** or see mount iso in linux
4. Navigate to the SYSMGMT/srvadmin/linux/supportscripts directory.
5. Run the srvadmin-install.sh shell script as shown below, which performs an express installation. **sh srvadmin-install.sh -x**
6. Server Administrator services do not start automatically.  Start the Server Administrator services after the installation using the srvadmin-services.sh script
   **sh srvadmin-services start**
7. add /opt/dell/srvadmin/bin to your path